# BASKETBALL FRVR?

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

You might already be familiar with the game: [Basketball FRVR](https://www.facebook.com/basketballfrvrgame/) in facebook. There are two types of score you can make:

- **A virgin-shot:**(we call it so in our country :D) When the ball enters the basket without touching the rim  or
- **A stale shot:** When the ball enters the basket, but after touching the rim.

The game is over once you miss a shot. Stale shot always scores 2 points.The first in a run of consecutive virgin-shots scores 3 points, the second scores 6 points, and subsequent ones score 9 points each.

For example,

```
Hits             Total score 

S-V-V-V          2+3+6+9 = 20
S-V-V-V-V        2+3+6+9+9 = 29 (see how added score for consecutive virgin-
                                 shots                              
                                 saturates at the 5th hit)
S-V-S-V-V-S-V    2+3+2+3+6+2+3= 21
```

Using simple mathematics, it can easily [be](http://www.nepposts.com/weird-score-calculation-in-basketball-frvr/) proven that any score greater than 1 `n>1` can be scored in the game

## The Challenge

For any given number `1<n<100`, output all the possible ways to score `n`.

## Rules:

- You can either write a complete program or function(s), snippets however are not acceptable.
- Hard-coding the output or loading from memory/other programs/website is strictly prohibited, you must compute the output in real-time.
- The output must be a well-separated collection of string of `S`s and `V`s. For eg: `['SVS','SSV','VSS']` or `{'SVS','SSV','VSS'}`.
- It is encouraged to, but the collection need not be sorted or contain only unique elements. Brownie points if you output sorted and unique collection of strings.

## Winning condition:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

## Input/Output (Test-cases)

```
2: {'S'}
3: {'V'}
4: {'SS'}
12: {'SSSSSS', 'VSSVS', 'VSVSS', 'VSSSV', 'SSVSV', 'SVSVS', 'SVSSV'}
16: {'SSSVSVS', 'SSSVSSV', 'VSSSSSV', 'SSVSSVS', 'SVVSV', 'VSSSSVS', 'SVSVV', 'SVSSSSV', 'VVSSV', 'VSVVS', 'SVSVSSS', 'SVSSSVS', 'VSSVSSS', 'SSVSSSV', 'SSSSSSSS', 'VVSVS', 'VSSSVSS', 'SVSSVSS', 'VSVSSSS', 'SSSSVSV', 'SSVSVSS', 'VSSVV'}
```

Thanks to [Peter Taylor](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/194/peter-taylor) for improving this question

Comment: In case anyone cares, as an American, I always called rimless (and backboardless) shots "swishes" (and [Wikipedia backs me up here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swish): `Swish, a basketball shot that goes through the basket without touching the rim or backboard`)

Comment: I'm mostly just curious where they call them 'virgin shots'... I'm afraid to look it up behind my company's firewall xD

Comment: @bendl Nepal or N*p*l when censored. xD

Comment: Very nice question—not hard, but definitely not trivial, and allows for different approaches :)

Comment: I think 28 should be 29 in the second test case.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you. @JulianWolf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
o2,5ṁo8‘
Hṗ@€⁾VSẎðOḂŒgÇ€FS=ðÐf
```

A monadic link returning a list of the strings (lists of characters).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9qZWxsef//bzIsNeG5gW844oCYCkjhuZdA4oKs4oG@VlPhuo7DsE/huILFkmfDh@KCrEZTPcOww5Bm/8OHWf//MTI)** - The footer calls the link and separates the entries by newlines since a full program's implicit output would smash them together.

#### How?

```
o2,5ṁo8‘ - Link 1, helper to form shot scores: list of shots grouped by type (S=1 and V=0)
         -                                e.g. [[1,1],[0,0,0,0,0],[1,1],[0],[1,1]]
 2,5     - 2 paired with 5 = [2,5]
o        - logical or (vectorises)             [[1,1],[2,5,0,0,0],[1,1],[2,5],[1,1]]
    ṁ    - mould like the input                [[1,1],[2,5,0,0,0],[1,1],[2],[1,1]]
     o8  - logical or with 8                   [[1,1],[2,5,8,8,8],[1,1],[2],[1,1]]
       ‘ - increment                           [[2,2],[3,6,9,9,9],[2,2],[3],[2,2]]

Hṗ@€⁾VSẎðOḂŒgÇ€FS=ðÐf - Link: number, total score, n
H                     - halve n
    ⁾VS               - literal ['V','S']
 ṗ@€                  - Cartesian power with swapped @rguments for €ach
                      -   ...i.e. for each in [1,2,...,floor(half n)]
                      -   yielding all strings of Vs and Ss from length 1 to floor(half n)
       Ẏ              - tighten (from a list of lists of lists to a list of lists)
        ð         ðÐf - filter keep those entries for which this yields a truthy value:
         O            -   cast to ordinals (S->83, V->86)
          Ḃ           -   modulo 2         (S->1, V->0)
           Œg         -   group equal runs (e.g. [0,0,1,1,0] -> [[0,0],[1,1],[0]])
             Ç€       -   call the last link (1) as a monad for €ach (transform to scores)
               F      -   flatten (make one list of scores)
                S     -   sum (calculate the total score of the string)
                 =    -   equals right argument (n)?
```

The resulting order is actually lexicographical in reverse, to have it forward sorted just reverse it by appending `Ṛ`.

Comment: Nice. Your brownie .

Comment: @officialaimm We usually call those cookies but whatever...

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>73</s> 72 bytes

Prints all unique, lexically sorted combinations.

```js
f=(n,p=0,s='')=>n?n>1&&f(n-2,0,s+'S')&f(n-(p-9?p+=3:9),p,s+'V'):alert(s)
```

#### Test cases

In this snippet, `alert()` has been replaced by `console.log()` for user-friendliness.

```js
f=(n,p=0,s='')=>n?n>1&&f(n-2,0,s+'S')&f(n-(p-9?p+=3:9),p,s+'V'):console.log(s)

;[2, 3, 4, 12, 16]
.forEach(n => { console.log('[' + n + ']'); f(n); })
```

Comment: Here's a crunchy brownie: 

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>96</s> <s>95</s> <s>85</s> <s>77</s> 73 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @notjagan*
*-4 bytes thanks to @xnor*

```python
f=lambda x,s='',i=3:f(x-2,s+'S')+f(x-i,s+'V',3*(i<9)+i)if x>0 else[s]*-~x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcexCsIwEADQ3a@47XLNFdpEBIvxJwou4lCxhwc1LU2HuPjrkb7tLd/tPUdfioRp@DxfA2ROAZE1@E5Mrh0niz2S3aN7bsi@Mno5k1VSgXxtYJzSeE@Pqv7lIvMKChrBsecjt47bU3cAWFaNm1EWo0TlDw)

Comment: You can remove a byte by changing `x==0` to `x<1`.

Comment: Recursive functions that print can usually be shortened to instead produce a list. In place of printing, return a list of length 1 or 0, and recursively sum the lists corresponding to the branches.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP>=7.1, 158 bytes

```php
function b($s="",$g=0){global$r,$i;$g-$i?$g>$i?:b($s."2",$g+2)&b($s.($n=$s[-1]>2?min(9,$s[-1]+3):3),$g+$n):$r[]=strtr($s,2369,SVVV);}$i=$argn;b();print_r($r);
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e5b55f78e8bd6fc7b2f3a266acc0251a22b2484)

Expanded

```php
function b($s="",$g=0){
  global$r,$i;
  $g-$i
    ?$g>$i
      ?
      :b($s."2",$g+2) # recursive call add a S
      &b($s.($n=$s[-1]>2?min(9,$s[-1]+3):3),$g+$n) # recursive call add a V
    :$r[]=strtr($s,2369,SVVV); # add to result array if reach score replace integers with S and V
} 
$i=$argn; #short input variable
b(); #call the function
print_r($r); #print results
```

Comment: @officialaimm You must use a PHP Version equal greater than 7.1

Comment: @officialaimm you can change the version to the highest available version. At the first time you visit the site it is not set to a PHP 7.1 Version And the only output I reach for input=6 with a Version 7.1 is `SSS`

Comment: Oh, its fine now.Anyways,  its quite weird how different versions of PHP are giving different outputs for the same code though.. :D

Comment: @officialaimm This depends on the new feature in PHP 7.1 that is use in this case. `$string[-1]` belongs to `""` in all versions under 7.1 http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 95 <del>102</del> <del>105</del> <del>112</del> bytes

```
If[#4==#2,Echo@#,If[#4>#2,#0[#<>"S",#2+2,0,#4];#0[#<>"V",#2+Min[3#3+3,9],#3+1,#4]]]&["",0,0,#]&
```

There should be a lot of golfing potential.

Bascially it is a recursive function that perform a DFS over all possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 75 bytes

```
n#v|n<1=[[]|n==0]|n>0=(('S':)<$>(n-2)#3)++(('V':)<$>(n-v)#min(v+3)9)
f=(#3)
```

Call `f` with the total score value. Uses a fairly straightforward depth-first search to find all the solutions. Sadly, Haskell's precedence rules seem to be out to get me today, so there are lots of parentheses here.

Comment: As @Laikoni pointed, `VVVV` should evaluate to 27 while you seem to evaluate it as 30.

Comment: Fixed the truncation problem at the cost of a few bytes. Thanks, @Laikoni, for pointing that out.

Comment: @Laikoni If I change `<$>` to `map`, I have to wrap the `#` call in parentheses, so it's a wash.